# How to filter in crossfilter by current date and yesterday's date?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

I want to make a query in crossfilter to filter all data from today's date.

Example: I have this query:

```
var countPerDim2 = Dim2.filterExact("1.1.2018").group().reduceSum();
```

So crossfilter will filter data from 1.1.2018.

But I want crossfilter to automatically get the the current date.
My reason is that I want to draw two charts to compare them.
Like :

Chart 1 by Date 1.1.2018 and Chart 2 by Date 31.12.17

How can I get the filter by yesterday's date? Is there a function like `datenow()` for the current day and maybe `datenow(-1)` for yesterday's date?

Thank you and happy new year!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Today and yesterday

To answer your immediate question, JavaScript's `new Date()` will return the current time and date as a JavaScript `Date` object. Then you just need to convert the date object to a string to match your date format.

You can use [d3.time.format](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Time-Formatting.md#format) to produce those strings. Looks like you would want something like

```
d3.time.format('%-d.%-m.%Y')
```

(or perhaps with `m` and `d` reversed - unclear from your example whether month or day comes first)

Yesterday is something like

```
var date = new Date();
date.setDate(date.getDate()-1);
```

See the [JavaScript Date documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) for more details.

#### Comparing two days

However, I think you'll run into a more fundamental problem, which is that crossfilter doesn't have the concept of multiple filters, so it's hard to compare one date against another in side-by-side charts.

Off the top of my head, the best thing I can think of is to "freeze" a group using a fake group:

```
function freeze_group(group) {
    var _all = group.all().slice();
    return {
        all: function() {
            return _all;
        }
    };
}
```

You'd apply one date filter, then call

```
chart.group(freeze_group(group));
```

on the chart you want to have that date. Now it won't change when the filter changes, and you can apply the other date filter for other charts.

Comment: Thank you very much Gordon!